# Is there any way to get SMTP server name value from php.ini

Tags: php, email, smtp

Is there any way to get SMTP server name value from php.ini so that I don't need to repeat that name explicitly in application's config file?

On my local machine, I use WAMP stack, and application is deployed on LAMP stack.

Comment: Have you looked at `ini_get()`?

Comment: I knew it was something simple but somehow could not find anything while searching. And believe me I tried. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you, and it is okay to ask. It's just that this is not really a question IMHO. But no problem to ask. You will now see many just popping you with answers, but I suggest to benefit from your question, write an answer your own! (that is perfectly alright and you can accept it as well)

Comment: Usually, I find the answer before posting a question somewhere because it was already asked. But this time neither Google nor direct searching in SO gave me the answer I was looking for. Basically, this question (with a few modifications) was the query I was using.

Comment: No problem, the next one that uses the exact search phrase will find it here. If you answer the question your own you will better remember in the future as well. So there is use for you and for others. Just go ahead.

Comment: And please add to your question which operating system you are using. I can imagine this differs across platforms, so this would be good to know.

Comment: Well, it's seems unfair to me to use answer of other people =) It would be different if I had found the answer somewhere else myself. I will just accept answer of the first poster. He's a new guy in here, so it's even better =) And I will definitely remember answer to this question know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
    ini_get("SMTP");  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

var_dump( ini_get( 'SMTP' ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In honesty, this depends on how you are accessing your mailing functions. Even though your SMTP server internally might be `localhost` and to the php.ini it might be that your SMTP might, in reality, actually be `mail.x.co.uk` to everyone else.

Which version you use depends upon what your using it for.

Comment: On my local machine, I use my ISP's SMTP server, and when I deploy the application it has to be that server's SMTP value. That's why I asked how to get it so I don't have to modify the config.

Comment: @Vitalius Ok kool then your fine here